# Printing content of text files by retrieving from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, file

I store number of text files in the mysql database and need to retrieve them to count each end every program's some features such as "white spaces,num of while loops" etc.

I saved the files in the database with type BLOB. And this is how I retrieve the files. But it prints only the first text file but not all.. The rs.next doesn't work as a loop and show me the other file contents. For first file it works well. Could someone please let me know why this happens?

```
public class DbPersister {
private Connection conn;

public DbPersister(){
conn=DatabaseConnectionFactory.getConnection();
}

public void getTheFile(){

    try {
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String query="SELECT Prog_Num,File FROM file_details";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);


        while(rs.next()){

        int prog_num=rs.getInt("Prog_Num");
        String file= rs.getString("File");

            System.out.println("////////////////////////////////////////"+prog_num+"//////////////////////////////////////////////////////");


      FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(fr);

      while(bReader.readLine()!=null){
          System.out.println(bReader.readLine());
      }


      }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbPersister.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbPersister.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

And I have taken the file type as string . is it correct. Files could be very large.

Comment: What language is that? You've only tagged with with 'mysql', not the language the code is written in!

Comment: sorry.. corrected...